# Saving Image to gcloud with firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I´d like to save a selected image from unsplash in a cloud function - to run it in background. Here´s my code:

```
export const getUnsplashCron = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .runWith({ memory: '512MB', timeoutSeconds: 15 })
  .https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {

    if (!req.query.url) {
      res.status(300).send('no url');
    }

    return request({
      url: req.query.url + '?client_id=' + environment.unsplash.appId,
      encoding: null
    }, (err, response, body) => {
      if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {

        const stream = require('stream');
        const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();

        bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(body, 'base64'));

        const file = admin.storage().bucket().file('name.jpg');

        bufferStream.pipe(
          file.createWriteStream({
            public: true
          }))
          .on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error)
          })
          .on('finish', function() {

            const config: GetSignedUrlConfig = {
              action: 'read',
              expires: '01-01-2025'
            };
            file.getSignedUrl(config, function(error, url) {
              console.log(url);
              if (error) {
                return res.status(500).send(error);
              }
              return res.status(500).send(url);
            });

          });


      }
    });

  });
```

But I´m getting an

> Error: Not Found
>      at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build /src/util.js:172:38)
>       at Util.handleResp (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:116:117)
>       at retryRequest (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:404:22)
>       at onResponse (/srv/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:200:7)
>       at /srv/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:158:17
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
>     code: 404,
>     errors: 
>      [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ],
>     response: undefined,
>     message: 'Not Found' }

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use promises to handle asynchronous tasks (like the HTTP call to unsplash, or the write to Cloud Storage). By default `request` does not return promises, so you need to use an interface wrapper for request, like [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

You should therefore modify your code as follows:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
.....

export const getUnsplashCron = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .runWith({ memory: '512MB', timeoutSeconds: 15 })
  .https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {

  .......

  const options = {
    uri: req.query.url + '?client_id=' + environment.unsplash.appId
  };

  rp(options)
    .then(response => {
      .... //Upload your file
      res.send('Success');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // API call failed...
      res.status(500).send('Error': err);
    });
};
```

You may watch this official video series for more detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ (in particular the 3 videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises").

Comment: @Coach Hello, did you have time to look at this anwser?